# Array Issues with Java

Tags: java, arrays

Im having Difficulty with programming, I'm new at this so I'll send the whole program so far and I just need help with case '2' please! it says It cannot find symbol Variable array.

```
    import java.util.Scanner ;
    public class jakegrimson20062582 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                // Local variable
                int option;
                String squareFootage;
                int noBed;

                Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
                Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );


            // Display menu graphics
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("|  *****Rental Menu*******   |");
            System.out.println("|        1. Enter rental property Details     ");
            System.out.println("|        2. Enter monthly rent ( 12 Months )       ");
            System.out.println("|        3. Display Annual Rent");
            System.out.println("|        4. Display rental report       ");
            System.out.println("|        5. Display Monthly rents falling below a                certain threshold       ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" Please Select an option: ");
            option = input.nextInt();

    // Switch construct
    switch (option) {
    case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter Rental Details: ");
            System.out.println("Property Code:            ");
            String propertyCode = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("Property Type:            ");
            String propertyType = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("Square Footage:           ");
            squareFootage = user_input.next();
            System.out.println("Number Of bedrooms        ");
            noBed = input.nextInt();
            break;


      case 2:
{
           Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           int[] array;
           array = new int[12];



           // creates for loop 
           for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
          {
           System.out.println("Enter Rental for month");
           array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextInt();
          }

          for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
        {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

}



      System.out.println("");
     break;

     case 3:
      System.out.println("Exit selected");

      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Invalid selection");
      break; 

  }
}
}
```

I require help with completing this code, **NOT JUST THIS ISSUE** all help On the finished code would be MUCH appreciated, as On the topic I'm having general issues with arrays, I may need a string version of this code rather than INT due to the fact that numbers put in with have a decimal point. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent your code to be human-readable:

```
case 2:
{
    Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array;
    array = new int[12];

    // creates for loop 
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Rental for month");
        array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextInt();
    }
}

// prints i in the for loop

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

This makes the error a lot more obvious.  You're creating a code block in the `case 2` block with some curly braces `{}`, and you declare your `array` variable *inside* of that block.  That means the variable is scoped only to that block.  Then you try to access the variable outside of that block, where it no longer exists.

Should that `for` loop be *inside* the `{}` block?  Or perhaps should the curly braces for that block be omitted entirely, since a `case` doesn't need them?

Comment: Ah.. yes.. It certainly should be. *sigh* how did I miss that.

Comment: I think you can have as many statements after a `case` as you want, that part is fine. The `array` access is out of scope though.

Comment: @biziclop: Interesting, I guess maybe the `{}` might be throwing me off.  (My Java is a bit rusty.)  Do those just enclose a block and have nothing to do with the `case` then?  I'll update the answer...

Comment: @JakeGrim Simply because the code wasn't clearly indented. We all miss the obvious sometimes but certain cases are fully avoidable by following good practices.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't having issues reading it due to BlueJ changing it all to be boxed though, My apologies on the indenting I never thought to do so, Would you be aware of how to change this coding to string format rather than INT? I'm having that issue now after correcting what you said.

Comment: @David Yes, according to the JLS any number of statements can follow the case label, including blocks. But to avoid confusion, I always make sure that my `case`s are either a single block or a single statement followed by a `break` statement.

Comment: Also is there a way to Display what number of array it is when it runs like
Enter rental for month[1] = (number entered by user)
Enter rental for month[2] = (number entered by user)

Comment: @JakeGrim This isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. You ask one question, you get an answer for that and case closed. If you have another question, unrelated to the first one, you should ask another question. But only after trying to search for an existing one. Try to search for "java convert string to int" and pick the answer you like best.

Comment: In general, whenever you have a problem, it's a good idea for your first thought to be "Am I the first person in the world to have this problem?" In an overwhelming majority of the cases the answer is that "You're not even in the first million." And if that is the case, the answer is probably already there on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper formatting so you can see where your case 2 ends. The array variable only exists inside case 2, and you're trying to use it outside of that scope.